# Django Tags/Filter and Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this project:

```
app/
app/Items/
app/Management/
...
```

in `Management` I have `templatetags` , where I have my tags for whole project.

```
app/Management/templatetags/main_filters.py
app/Management/templatetags/__init__.py
```

In this **file** I have:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='createmenu')
def createmenu(value):
...
```

then in **html** template I have:

```
{%load main_filters%}
...
{{dataList|createmenu}}
...
```

and the **settings.py** I have into INSTALLED_APPS :

```
...
"Management.templatetags",
...
```

and finally I always have next error:

```
'main_filters' is not a valid tag library: 
Template library main_filters not found, tried django.templatetags.main_filters,
django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.main_filters,
django.contrib.admin.templatetags.main_filters
```

I've tried put it (`./Management/templatetags Folder`) inside folder **ITEMS** and changed in `settings.py`, with `Items.templatetags` , and it works. What is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want `"Management",` instead of `"Management.templatetags",` inside `INSTALLED_APPS`. The error also hints that `Management` is not installed and thus `Management.templatetags` does not get checked against `main_filters`

Comment: It works! your solution works!

Comment: cool, I've posted it in detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want "Management", instead of "Management.templatetags", inside `INSTALLED_APPS`. modules inside `templatetags` of a installed app gets loaded automatically as long as `{% load %}` is invoked.

Also, the error shows that only three paths have been checked

> > > ...tried django.templatetags.main_filters,
> > >       django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.main_filters,
> > >       django.contrib.admin.templatetags.main_filters

We could then conclude that `Management.templatetags.main_filters` does not get checked, usually there are several reasons:

1. missing of `__init__.py` in `templatetags` directory. You have one.
2. `Management` is not installed correctly. The case.
3. weird import issues... luckily not =)